How can I add a legend to a ggplot when there is not an aesthetic?
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(wt=4, mpg=25)
df2 <- tibble(wt=2, mpg=15)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_point(data=df1, aes(x=wt, y=mpg), color="red", size=3) +
    geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=wt, y=mpg), color="blue", size=3)


Is there a way in ggplot that I can manually add a legend for the df1 and df2 data points as I have demo'd below (albeit using Preview)?

I can get a legend by binding the dataframes together ...
df1 <- tibble(wt=4, mpg=25, source='My Car')
df2 <- tibble(wt=2, mpg=15, source='Your Car')
df <- bind_rows(mtcars, df1, df2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color = source)) + 
    geom_point() 


... but I often find I want to manually add a legend, but am unsure of how to do so except in an outside tool like Google Slides.

This q&a should get you there.

So aes(color = 'My Car') and aes(color = 'Your Car') with scale_color_manual(values = c('My car' = 'red', 'Your car' = 'blue').

ggplot will only build a legend for aesthetic properties that are mapped to values. You don't have to combine data if you don't want (though that makes things easier), but you do have to make values to color inside the aes(). See dups for examples
